# Makefile - Compile Single Objects in different directory

Tags: gcc, makefile, gnu-make

I have been combing the web and I can't figure out the right way to get this to work. Just trying to create a simple Makefile which takes my source and only builds the changed files. I need all the .o files to be put in the same output folder. I currently have everything working except that if I change one file the whole thing rebuilds. For example, if I change main.c it will compile EOL.c as well. However if nothing changes it says nothing needs to be done.

```
NAME=Program

CC=arm-none-eabi-gcc
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -O0  -std=c99 \
-nostartfiles --specs=nano.specs \
-mthumb -fmessage-length=0 \
-fsigned-char -ffunction-sections \
-fdata-sections -mcpu=cortex-m0

BID?=_DEV
DEFINES= -DPROD -DBLD_ID=\"$(BID)\"
LDFLAGS= -nostartfiles 
INCLUDES= -ISrc/App/Include -ISrc/Device/CMSIS/Include 
SOURCES= Src/main.c Src/App/Source/Application.c Src/App/Source/EOL.c Src/Svc/Source/TimerManager.c
OBJECTS=$(OBJECTS1:.c=.o)
OBJECTS1=$(SOURCES:.S=.o)
OFILES1=$(notdir ${OBJECTS})
OFILES=$(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(OFILES1))
OBJDIR=Output

.PHONY: all rebuild clean

all: $(OBJDIR) $(SOURCES) $(OBJDIR)/$(NAME).hex

%.hex: %.elf
    arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O ihex $< $@

%elf: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OFILES) -o $@


rebuild: clean all

.SECONDARY:
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDES) $< -o $(OBJDIR)/$(notdir $@)

.S.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDES) $< -o $(OBJDIR)/$(notdir $@)

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir $(OBJDIR)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJDIR)/*.o $(OBJDIR)/*.elf $(OBJDIR)/*.hex $(OBJDIR)/*.bin
```

Comment: I don't see relation of "cmake" tag with the problem. CMake is not Make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with this makefile. Basically you have rules whose targets are not the files they actually produce, and a rule whose prerequisites are not the files it actually needs.

Suppose you have modified `Src/main.c` and try to rebuild `Output/Program.elf` using this rule:

```
%elf: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OFILES) -o $@
```

The prerequisites (`$(OBJECTS)`) are actually `Src/main.o Src/App/Source/EOL.o` and so on. These files do not exist -- they *never* exist -- but there is a rule for them:

```
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDES) $< -o $(OBJDIR)/$(notdir $@)
```

Make sees that `Src/main.o` depends on `Src/main.c` and must therefore be rebuilt, as must `Output/Program.elf`. So it invokes this rule -- which actually builds `Output/main.o`. But the elf rule demands *all* of the (imaginary) object files, so all of the sources must be recompiled-- into object files that already exist and are not out of date, but which Make wasn't paying attention to.

The first thing to do is fix the object rules, but there's a problem: although the rules are flawed, they have the advantage of helping Make to find the corresponding source files (before misusing them), like this:

```
Src/App/Source/EOL.o: Src/App/Source/EOL.c
    ...
```

How can we tell Make where to find the source file corresponding to `Output/EOL.o`? There's more than one way, but a good way is by using [vpath](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Selective-Search):

```
vpath %.c Src/App/Source

Output/EOL.o: EOL.c
   ...
```

All we have to do is create a list of source directories, pass it to vpath, and modify the pattern rule:

```
SRCDIRS := $(dir $(SOURCES))
vpath %.c $(SRCDIRS)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDES) $< -o $@
```

(The `.S.o` rule can be fixed the same way.)

Then modify the `elf` rule to name -- and use -- its real prerequisites:

```
%elf: $(OFILES)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```